# how to get parent div attribute values in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need data-offerId of parent div but it's not working properly. Please suggest me.

**HTML**

```
<div class="rows" data-offerid="123487 ">15<span class="mth">.– /mth</span><span class="clear-row"></span></div>
<div class="rows" data-offerid="123486 ">15<span class="mth">.– /mth</span><span class="clear-row"></span></div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
 $('.clear-row').click(function(){
     var offers = $('.clear-row').parent().attr('data-offerid');
     console.log(offers);
 });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the parent element value using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174947/how-to-get-the-parent-element-value-using-jquery)

Comment: try `.parent().data('offerid');`

Comment: Sometimes `$(".clear-row").closest("div")` works better than `parent()`

Answer (score 6):

Inside the handler, you should be using `this` not repeating the selector `.clear-row`

```
$('.clear-row').click(function(){
   var offers = $(this).parent().attr('data-offerid');
   console.log(offers);
});
```

You can also use `data()` instead of `attr()`

```
var offers = $(this).parent().data('offerid');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with one more way using `jQuery` `closest` method https://jsfiddle.net/464g5hzq/

```js
$('.clear-row').click(function(){
  var offers = $(this).closest('div.rows').data('offerid');
  console.log(offers);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rows" data-offerid="123487 ">15<span class="mth">.– /mth</span><span class="clear-row"></span></div>
<div class="rows" data-offerid="123486 ">15<span class="mth">.– /mth</span><span class="clear-row"></span></div>
```

Instead of using `.attr` to get the `data attribute`, please use `.data(attribute-name);` if you have `data attribute` like `data-offerid`.

Hope this will be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` inside your click event, to target the `cleararrow` element your clicked on

```
$(this).parent().attr('data-offerid')

$('.clear-row').click(function() {
  var offers = $(this).parent().attr('data-offerid');
  console.log(offers);
});
```

**Working example**

```js
$('.clear-row').click(function() {
  var offers = $(this).parent().attr('data-offerid');
  console.log(offers);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rows" data-offerid="123487 ">15<span class="mth">.– /mth</span><span class="clear-row">clear</span></div>
<div class="rows" data-offerid="123486 ">15<span class="mth">.– /mth</span><span class="clear-row">clear</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$('.clear-row').click(function(){
    var offers = $(this).parent().attr('data-offerid');
    console.log(offers);
});

//OR

var offers = this.parentNode.getAttribute("data-offerid");   // plain javascript
```

Helper Link to understand: [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: WHy did you switch from jquery back to vanilla JS? And in any case the vanilla version doesnt do anything like the jquery version

Comment: Just for a reference sir. The user has added `javascript` in question tag so I had just added it here.